# Chrome throws Mixed Content error while downloading exe file from windows service over http

Tags: .net, google-chrome, windows-services, mixed-content

I have a ASP.NET website hosted on a public server over https and a windows service running on one of the machines at client site.

On clicking a link from the public site opened in Chrome on any machine at client site, it redirects to the windows service using a local IP address and port (e.g. http://192.168.2.139:8086/data/installer.exe) and downloads the exe file.

This worked fine until a few weeks ago, before Chrome was updated to latest.

Now, it gives the following error:

> MixedContent: The site at 'https://mypublicsite.com/' was loaded over
> a secure connection, but the file at
> 'http://192.168.2.139:8086/data/installer.exe' was redirected through
> an insecure connection.  This file should be served over HTTPS. This
> download has been blocked. See
> https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html
> for more details.

[Error shown in developer tools in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfEpc.png)

One option that I tried was to host the local windows service on https by generating a SSL certificate using http://www.allenconway.net/2012/02/applying-and-using-ssl-certificate-with.html But I am unable to figure out how do I create and associate certificate with my windows service. Is there a better way to address this issue without using certificates?